# Jquery FullCalendar Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to put my JSON data (which I succesfully get)  into events in FullCalendar Plugin, but unfortunetly It doesnt work for me...

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/test/2014-09-09", function (data, stat) {
                alert(data[0].dates[0].dateStart)
start:data[0].dates[0].dateStart
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please make a jsFiddle that illustrates your problem.  Since localhost is YOUR machine, you'll need to hardcode the returned json string.

Comment: Call the callback with the events that you fetched

Answer (score 0):

I had same thing in my previous project something like this. I was also getting data in JSON format.

I loop my JSON data and them on fullCalendar as below

First make function

```
function Event(_id, _title, _start, _color, _editable, _inspectorID, _complaintID, _productID, _seasonYearID, _inspectionType) {
var newEvent = new Object();

newEvent.id = _id;
newEvent.title = _title;
newEvent.start = _start;
newEvent.color = _color;
newEvent.editable = _editable;
newEvent.allDay = true;
newEvent.durationEditable = false;
/* Custom Properties*/
newEvent.InspectorID = _inspectorID;
return newEvent;
 }
```

Then add to the calender this object as below

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', Event(newID, productName, _events.Date, "#" + _events.EventColor, editable, _events.InspectorID));
```

Hope this will help you.